Trigonometry question regarding circumcircles of triangles
Question is as follows:
If O is the circumcentre of triangle ABC, prove that the ratio of the radii of the circumcircles of triangles ABC, OBC is $2 \cos A : 1$.
Not sure how to get started on this one. The book (Trigonometry by Nobbs) has not yet covered inscribed, escribed circles yet but solutions to triangles has just been covered. The question is from a chapter entitled 'Applications to Triangles'.
Apologies for no working as I'm not sure where to start. Any hints would be gratefully received.
Many thanks in advanced.

Let $R_1$ be the circumradius of $\triangle OBC$ and $R$ that of $\triangle ABC$. Then area $[OBC]=\frac{R\cdot R\cdot a}{4R_1}$, where $R_1$. Note that the angle $\angle BOC=2A$. So, $[OBC]=\frac{R\cdot R\cdot \sin(2A)}{2}$. Simplify, using that $\sin(2A)=2\sin(A)\cos(A)$ and law of sines $\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=2R$.

More directly, extended sine rule states that $ \frac{BC}{\sin \alpha} = 2R$, so the ratio is $ \sin 2 \alpha / \sin \alpha = 2 \cos \alpha$.

Thank you for both replies. It makes perfect sense now.
